# How many possible outcomes to pull two cards of the same suit from a deck of cards?

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

In a standard deck of cards, how many possible outcomes are there to pull two of the same suit cards without replacing the first ones? I calculated that the probability of doing this is 4/17 and I got that by multiplying 52/52 x 12/51. I just don't know how to find how many possible outcomes (sample points) there are for this type of problem.

Comment: That's a good way to look at it and the right answer. Someone who's unnecessarily fond of combinatorial symbols might write it as $4{13\choose 2}{39\choose 0}/{52\choose 2},$ which simplifies to your answer.

Comment: What you calculated correctly is the probability of randomly drawing two cards of the same suit from a standard deck of cards.  However, the question in the title asks for the number of ways of selecting two cards of the same suit from a standard deck of cards, which is a different question.  Which question are you trying to answer?

Comment: Hint:  $\frac{52}{52}\times\frac{12}{51} =\frac{52 \times 12}{52 \times 51}$ based on the order of your pair mattering or $\dfrac{\frac{52 \times 12}{2}}{\frac{52 \times 51}{2}}$ if not